# Possible bug when using tikz to position node using pos command in curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-node

Runing this simple code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[-latex]
            (0,0) to[out=40, in= 140] (5,0) node [pos=0.5] {en};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Results in the text "en" not being located in the middle of the path.
[image: Example]

Using `midway` resulted in the same problem.

Comment: No bug I think, has to do with how `to` paths work. You need to place `node {..}` immediately after `to[..]`, before the last coordinate.